# Can't access custom value from point HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have some problems trying to access a custom value. My data array looks like this:

```
data: [ 
    { x:Date.UTC(2017,0,19,13,21, 0),y: 28.7 , shot : 197},
    { x:Date.UTC(2017,0,19,13,25, 0),y: 23.8 , shot : 199},{ ....
```

And my tooltip funtion like this:

```
tooltip: {
   useHTML: true,
   formatter: function() { 
      return '<b>Date:</b>'+new Date(this.x)+'<br><b>value:  </b>'+this.y+'<br><b>shot:</b>'+this.point.shot+'<br>' ;
  }
},
```

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/lvevano/vhkyhoLz/

It seems that "this.point.shot" doesnt work, and the tooltip is not shown. This is the error thrown

TypeError: this.point.shot is undefined

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this.point is undefined is because your tooltip is 'shared'. This is [default](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.shared) for highstock charts. To access your point use

```
this.points[0].point
```

or add shared: false to your tooltip like this:

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  shared: false,
  formatter: function() { 
      return '<b>Date:</b>'+new Date(this.x)+'<br><b>value:</b>'+this.y+'<br><b>shot:</b>'+this.point.shot+'<br>' ;
  }
},
```